# How do I start ipython's qtconsole cleanly on Win7

Tags: windows-7, ipython, qtconsole

I have python 3.4 and ipython 2.3.1 installed on Windows 7.  I installed ipython using pip from a wheel from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (Thanks, Chris!).  This install procedure does not create any start menu shortcuts, even when run as administrator.  I can successfully run "ipython qtconsole" from a cmd window, but then I have to have that command window open and the process doesn't fork--it's just and extra window hosting the child process.  If I create a shortcut to do the same, it opens a cmd window which then opens the qtconsole.

So, how do I start qtconsole without having an extra cmd window?  In previous versions, you could invoke python to run the ipython-console script, but that seems to be done away with now, in favor of a dedicated exe that appears to do the same...but waits for it to finish.  Is there a way I can start qtconsole without waiting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found something [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython), and then tried a few things and hence found that this does it if typed in the `run` window

```
c:\python27\pythonw -c "import IPython; IPython.start_ipython(['qtconsole'])"
```

I guess it should also work for shortcuts.

*P.S: I am using python 2.7.9 with IPython 3.0.0 on windows 7*

Answer (score 4):

If you installed Python using [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda) then such a shortcut already exists under the name `Jupyter QTConsole`.