# how to launch recent Jupyter QtConsole on Windows without a console window

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, jupyter, qtconsole

[This older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593448/how-do-i-start-ipythons-qtconsole-cleanly-on-win7) appears to be out of date.

It used to be (based on [reading git repos](https://github.com/hyperspy/start_jupyter_cm/pull/3) and [the qtconsole issue tracker](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/issues/288)) you could launch the Jupyter QtConsole without a console window running the background with:

`pythonw -m jupyter qtconsole`

However, in recent versions of Jupyter, this still launches the background console window.

[image]

I am wondering if anyone knows how to launch the QtConsole without the annoying console window.  I know you can do this from the Anaconda Navigator program, but I don't want to launch one program so that I can then launch another program.  I would prefer to have a simple batch script or even a python script so that I can launch with a Start Menu shortcut

Running the module directly also does not work:

`pythonw -c "from qtconsole.qtconsoleapp import main; main()"`

This still launches a new console window as in the picture, so I don't really know if this is possible in some straightforward way, or if the Anaconda Navigator is doing some black magic to make this happen

Comment: It seems that "C:\Miniconda3\Scripts\jupyter-qtconsole.exe" is a console application, which automatically allocates a console if it doesn't inherit one, which obviously it won't inherit from pythonw.exe. Look for a non-console version in that directory. If there isn't one, you're going to need an adapter script that runs this command with a hidden or windowless console.

Comment: Which versions are you using? I don't see the problem with Py2.7 win64 + qtconsole 4.4.1

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Python 3.6 and Python 3.7 using Anaconda Distribution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- `%CONDA_PREFIX%\Scripts\jupyter-qtconsole.exe` marked as console executable ([`Subsystem` field in PE optional header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format#optional-header-windows-specific-fields-image-only))
- the `-m ipykernel_launcher <etc>` subprocess started with `python.exe` even if the launcher was started with `pythonw`.

  - This one I was able to track to `%CONDA_PREFIX%\share\jupyter\kernels\python3\kernel.json`. It uses a full path to the executable thus doesn't trigger [the logic in `jupyter_client\manager.py` that replaces certain patterns with `sys.executable`](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/blob/master/jupyter_client/manager.py#L161).

**Both of these are specific to Anaconda and do not happen with the stock Python.** As such, **file a bug against https://github.com/conda-forge/qtconsole-feedstock to get this fixed.**

These are the workarounds:

- For the first bug, run `pythonw <Scripts_dir>\jupyter-qtconsole-script.py` which is the script that the `.exe` wraps.
  (This is Anaconda-specific. Regular Python uses a different wrapping mechanism. Anaconda must be patching `setuptools` or something.)
- For the second one, replace the full path in the aforementioned `kernel.json` with "`python`". This change will be overwritten when you update the `ipykernel` package that this file belongs to (this can be checked by searching for it in `%CONDA_PREFIX%\pkgs`).

---

[The OP reports that this solution may break other Anaconda packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297593/how-to-launch-recent-jupyter-qtconsole-on-windows-without-a-console-window/52300401?noredirect=1#comment91767852_52300401). I believe those that break make assumptions about the availability of standard streams. Though it too counts as a bug in my book, it must be coming from the fact that Anaconda packages aren't tested with this setup.

---

To create a shortcut/batch file to run the above command in Anaconda Prompt environment, see e.g. [How to make batch files run in anaconda prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305569/how-to-make-batch-files-run-in-anaconda-prompt).

Comment: the information in that page is either specific to something about their custom winpython environment, or is just flat out of date.  Using a current Anaconda environment, this does not work

Comment: @VinceW. the idea here is to directly run the script that `Scripts\jupyter-qtconsole.exe` wraps. I remember that previously, it was indeed available as `<name>-script.py` -- that seems to have changed now.

Comment: if you have a working example, I would love to see it.  I have tried all variants that I know.  the jupyter-script.py simply imports main from qtconsole.qtconsoleapp and then runs main().  This process itself generates a new command window if run from pythonw.exe

Comment: so for example `pythonw -c "from qtconsole.qtconsoleapp import main; main()"` will launch a new cmd window that it uses to run the ipykernel.  I suppose its possible there is no good way around this, but people do find ways, I just don't know how it works

Comment: @VinceW. This seems to be fixed in the recent version of `qtconsole`. Gimme a sec to pinpoint the commit/PR.

Comment: @VinceW. Okay, that should do it.

Comment: thanks, now how can I upvote this more than once?  I added some further instructions in your answer that are again Anaconda specific in order to launch the QtConsole from the start menu.

Comment: @VinceW. I think you'll be able to award a bounty in a day or so :)

Comment: @VinceW. your suggested edit will likely be rejected as an "attempt to reply" because it clearly deviates from the question as asked (creating a batch file to run something in the same environment as Anaconda Console is a completely different concern). You may post your own answer with those details though.

Comment: Okay, will do that if the edit is rejected unless you want to add it as an appendix yourself. Seems unnecessary to have two answers but whatever

Comment: @VinceW. SO's principle is one-concern-per-question. So it's better fit for another question which can be referenced here instead (in particular, because I'm sure there are more robust/manageable ways to do that).

Comment: @VinceW. Actually, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305569/how-to-make-batch-files-run-in-anaconda-prompt

Comment: I have filed a bug as requested: https://github.com/conda-forge/qtconsole-feedstock/issues/15

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, don't know if its worth putting in the answer, but I have since figured out that this can break other apps.  JupyterLab for instance goes into an infinite kernel restarting loop.  YAY!

Comment: @VinceW. yes, this is worth putting into the answer: it's a drawback of the solution that one needs to be informed of when considering using it.